# A good Html rendering engine

Tags: html, rendering

I am looking for a Html rendering engine that has:

1. Support in a good designer tool that helps me with the syntax, understand my objects (warns me of type errors and non existing names of classes/methods) and validate my Html.
2. A nice readable way of mixing Html markup with common programming syntax, for each, if then
3. Support for sub - templates / functions (in the same file or in another file) which themselves use the same syntax
4. Possibility to use variables the common way, a = 1 ... a = a + b ... if a > c ...
5. Support for larger commonly used class libraries / mature languages (.Net / Java / RoR / Django / Php etc)
6. Produce pure clean markup

I think that's basically it ... Shouldn't be so hard I think, but I haven't found the perfect one yet.

Comment: Which ones have you already considered?

Comment: Most recently and with most enthusiasm: Asp.Net Ascx with code blocks. Comes close but has flaws. Especially when using another Ascx within a Ascx, then code blocks aren't evaluated.

Comment: Have you looked at ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Afaiu Asp.Net Mvc stumbles on pt 3. The best solution I found so far for calling subtemplates is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/01/13/take-your-mvc-user-controls-to-the-next-level.aspx but that's a non out of the box solution and also not finished yet.

Comment: Need to look at this as a way to include sub user controls in Ascx. No time just now. http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/07/10/a-less-simple-include-for-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Also MVC (with VS 2010) still cannot handle code in attribute strings "<%# MyObject.SomeMisspelldProperty %>" thats *really* bad imho. (No syntax check, no IntelliSense).

Comment: ReSharper Visual Studio addon helps out with code in attribute strings, great!

Comment: Do you mean HTML editor?

Comment: During my "research" I tried ERB, a good one. Haml also looks cool but I didnt get it to run in my IronRuby testenvironment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check 'ASP.NET MVC' out.

1. Visual studio 2010 is actually a great web development tool. I am especially happy about the javascript support. I haven't seen better so far in all editors I tried (which are the best known free editors). It supports auto-complete for all languages used. It also warns for Html validation errors. It also has an express edition which is free.
2. You can use pick your server-side language. vb.net or C#. It's up to you to pick what's more readable. Server-side code is wrapped between <% %> tags. In visual studio these tags are also displayed in their own color to make them stand out a bit. Seems like clean separation to me?
3. A templating system is supported with the usercontrols which are placed in separate files with the same syntax. Check it out and see if you like it
4. The standard .NET languages syntaxes are quite common and readable. But that is a personal choice off course.
5. Since you're using .NET you have access to all of it's libraries.
6. You can make your markup as clean as you want it to be, you can have full control over the Html that is produced.

Perhaps you don't like the style of programming or you don't like Microsoft (I know I don't :-)) but they might actually have a winner with this framework, it is very clean. Add to that the powerful Visual Studio 2010 and you are good to go. Besides that, Stackoverflow is written in it.

There are some good videos around to introduce you to the framework. The ones by Scott Hanselmann and Scott Guthrie got me on my feet pretty quick.

Comment: "pick your server-side language. vb.net or C#" -- Reminds me of "Oh, we got both kinds. We got country *and* western".  :-)

Comment: :) true, I dislike vb but C# is a quite nice for a static typed language I think. If you stick to the right features. And LINQ + entity framework can be pretty powerful in combination with ASP.NET MVC. But again it's also a matter of taste.

Comment: With <% inside quotes Visual Studio looses the intellisense support. Bit of a luxuary problem perhaps. And it is possible to solve using addon Resharper. I have decided to go for Asp Net Mvc, and look forward to Razor. I think C# is a bit ugly, but I think I'll manage. VB.Net just feels old. Don't know if I dare use any of the Iron-languages due to a bit of lacking support from MS (compared to the main langs).

Comment: Good choice, I feel the same way about the languages. would you mind marking question as answered if my comment helped you pick a framework?

Comment: MVC 3 + Razor ! Intellisense, functions (with @helper or @functions), nice markup, all good!

Answer (score 0):

Kompozer

For WYSIWYG and basic html:
kompozer.net

Notepad++ <-- I like this one more

For advanced, pure code:
http://notepad-plus-plus.org

And both are free :)